# Backup issue DirectAdmin - Centos 7

Tags: php, centos, directadmin

i hope that someone can help me with this.
In Centos 7 + DirectAdmin i have a problem when i wan to make a backup from all users as ADMIN.

I have googled tried alot of things but nothing helps...
I hope that someone can help me out with this 
I am ready to give a fee for this.

Error Message :

```
Error while backing up database admin_USER1
Error while backing up database admin_USER1: The sql file is 0 bytes in size: /home/admin/admin_backups/admin/backup/admin_USER1.sql
mysqldump error output: mysqldump: Got error: 1045: "Access denied for user 'da_admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" when trying to connect


<18:34:04>
Error while backing up database RES_USER2
Error while backing up database RES_USER2: The sql file is 0 bytes in size: /home/admin/admin_backups/ken/backup/RES_USER2.sql
mysqldump error output: mysqldump: Got error: 1045: "Access denied for user 'da_admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" when trying to connect

Error while backing up database RES_USER3
Error while backing up database RES_USER3: The sql file is 0 bytes in size: /home/admin/admin_backups/ken/backup/RES_USER3.sql
mysqldump error output: mysqldump: Got error: 1045: "Access denied for user 'da_admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" when trying to connect
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello,

There is an issues with the your da_admin mysql password. Your da_admin user is unable to connect mysql server and due to that you are getting this issues. You need to reset your da_admin mysql password. You can find out current password in /usr/local/directadmin/conf/mysql.conf file. Please check current password and try to reset that so that you will not get any issues with the backup. You can reset da_admin mysql password through following steps

http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=45